# VBA for "IF formula" with multiple results in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How can I convert this to VBA? Using this formula, it cover 6 rows only and the formula is already too long. My report has 600 rows.

`=IF(AND('Risk & Issue Log'!$K$2=$D5,'Risk & Issue Log'!$L$2=F$8,OR('Risk & Issue Log'!$F$2="Open",'Risk & Issue Log'!$F$2="In-progress")),'Risk & Issue Log'!$D$2," ")&IF(AND('Risk & Issue Log'!$K$3=$D5,'Risk & Issue Log'!$L$3=F$8,OR('Risk & Issue Log'!$F$3="Open",'Risk & Issue Log'!$F$3="In-progress")),'Risk & Issue Log'!$D$3," ")&IF(AND('Risk & Issue Log'!$K$4=$D5,'Risk & Issue Log'!$L$4=F$8,OR('Risk & Issue Log'!$F$4="Open",'Risk & Issue Log'!$F$4="In-progress")),'Risk & Issue Log'!$D$4," ")&IF(AND('Risk & Issue Log'!$K$5=$D5,'Risk & Issue Log'!$L$5=F$8,OR('Risk & Issue Log'!$F$5="Open",'Risk & Issue Log'!$F$5="In-progress")),'Risk & Issue Log'!$D$5," ")&IF(AND('Risk & Issue Log'!$K$6=$D5,'Risk & Issue Log'!$L$6=F$8,'Risk & Issue Log'!$F$5="Open"),'Risk & Issue Log'!$D$6," ")`

---

#### From Comments -

I want to -

1. compare each value on sheet `Risk & Issue Log` in column `K` to cell `D5`
2. compare each value on sheet `Risk & Issue Log` in column `L` to cell `F8`
3. compare each value on sheet `Risk & Issue Log` in column `F` to value `Open` or `In-progress`
4. For each `row` that I do this on, I want a result of the corresponding cell in column `D` if everything is `True` or a `blank` if anything is not a match.
5. I want the output to all be in a single cell separated by a comma and a space.

How would I go about doing this with VBA?

Comment: Can you please explain *in words* what you want? It's asking a lot for anyone to sit down and look at this giant formula and know what you want it to do.

Comment: You can't 'convert' it to VBA. You need to learn VBA and produce code to mimic this formula. This is likely the best you will get. Unless someone here is nice enough to sit down and convert it for you, but we aren't here to do people's work for them. If you have a specific question on VBA you can ask, but make a start yourself first.

Comment: Hello @MatthewWilliams , Thank you for that. I've been using using VBA for 2yrs but I only record and edit. I just would like to know if this is possible in VBA because it seems impossible in formula. I am thinking using a loop but i having a hard time. Appreciate all your answers.

Comment: @Excellll i am trying to code this formula in VBA. I am thinking about using a loop to repeat a formula's logical test up to the last row. And the result (value if true and value if false)should return in a single cell only.

Comment: Try explaining *what the formula does*

Comment: @Raystafarian , the formula is [ if(logical test, "value if true", "value if  false") ]. If the value in cell K2 is equal to the value in cell D2 and the value in L2 is equal to the value in F8 AND the value in F2 is "OPEN" or "In-progress", the result should be equal to the value in D2 otherwise it is BLANK.

Comment: And you want to do this for all cells in column K?

Comment: Sir @Raystafarian , there are two sheets, the first sheet is where K2, L2, and F2 are located. this sheet contains 600 rows. the second sheet is where the formula is written and where D2 and F2 is located, a summary sheet. In second sheet where my formula is written in a single cell should display the result for 600 rows. In a single cell, the value i want to display is the result of multiple formula combined using "&" [ex.. if(logtest,false,true) & if(logtest,false,true) & if(logtest,false,true) so on..]

Comment: I'm having real trouble understanding, is this an array formula?

Comment: 'Here's a sample vba.. 
Sub Sample()


Range("K2").Formula = "=IF(AND(F2=$M$2,G2=$M$3),A2,""korek"") & "", "" &" & _
                        "IF(AND(F3=$M$2,G3=$M$3),A3,""korek"")"
                    
End Sub

Comment: In the above code, it only covers two rows. my list have 600 rows. i don't want to repeat the code up to 600 rows like this..   IF(AND(F600=$M$600,G600=$M$600),A600,""korek"")"

Comment: It is not an array formula.. Array formula is entered using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. This one is just 2 or more formula's combined using "&" in between..

Comment: I found the same formula here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939537/how-to-loop-in-excel-without-vba-or-macros

Comment: Why is F2 being compared to M2 and G2 being compared to M3 THEN F3 also being compared to M2 and G3 also being compared to M3 BUT THEN F600 is compared to M600 and G600 to M600? This is where I'm confused. And you want your result to be in the format "value, value, value, value"? So the result for all tests is in one cell separated by commas?

Comment: This is why we need you to use words. Is it "for every value in column F compared to the same row in column M" or is it "for every value in column F compared to cell M2". After that is clarified, then you can add on "anything in column F can also be 'open' or 'in progress' in additional to..."

Comment: By making the question easy to understand what your result should look like and what you're trying to do, it helps us try to help you better. At this point your question is being down-voted and is in danger of being closed, in which case it won't be answered and we won't get the chance to help you. Check out what's [on topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), what makes [a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and what's [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand how StackExchange works.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me and how to make my future questions clearer. It is "for every value in column F compared to cell M2 and every value in column G compared to cell cell M3 and if the status (another column) is open or in-progress". If there is no match, the result is blank.The results i want if there are matches is "value, value, value, value, value"

Comment: Check the question and see if my edit and understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes sir. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it posts a WALL OF TEXT as a formula and asks the community to do the work without accurately describing the *problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through all of the comments and finally figuring out what you were trying to do (I think)... I believe the following UDF will work. Stick this in a new module in VBA and then in whatever cell you want to display the result type =summarizeLog() and hit enter.

```
Function summarizeLog() As String

    'Define some variables
    Dim shtLog As Worksheet
    Dim shtSum As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    'set the two worksheet variables
    Set shtLog = Sheets("Risk & Issue Log")
    Set shtSum = Sheets("Summary") '<---rename this to your needs


    'loop from 2 to 600 (these are the rows in your Risk & Issue Log to test, change to suit your needs)
    For i = 2 To 600

        'Now the test.
        'Does K2 through K600 equal D5, F2 through F600 equal either Open or In-Progress, and does L2 through L600 equal F8
        If shtLog.Range("K" & i).Value = shtSum.Range("D5") _
            And (shtLog.Range("F" & i).Value = "Open" Or shtLog.Range("F" & i).Value = "In-progress") _
            And shtLog.Range("L" & i).Value = shtSum.Range("F8") Then

            'If we passed, then grab the value in D for this row and append it the value that will be returned by this function
            '   (with a comma and space)
            summarizeLog = summarizeLog & ", " & shtLog.Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I am so impressed. I will test the codes right away. Thank you so much sir. Any suggestions of what book to read to learn Visual Basic? I am so interested.

Comment: It works. PERFECT!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I can't make any recommendations on VBA stuff. I've learned as I've needed it. I think the biggest hurdles are:

1. Basic programming stuff like If-then-else, for loops, etc..
2. How to reference and/or set content in a specific cell. Like Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").value or Sheets("Sheetname").cells(<row>,<column>).value
3. How to trigger the sub or function with worksheet events, or buttons, or a UDF call like I used in this example. 

You get those three and you can do 90% of anything you need in VBA. Look at examples and try before asking how.